# How to use sslAllowInvalidHostnames in mongo connection string in mongo-shell script?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I created a simple js script that uses two databases (ssh tunneled to ports 27019 and 27027), to run in with mongo shell. 
Of those databases have slightly stricter rules - requires ssl connection and do not allow connections from localhost.

If I connect to second database from terminal with --sslAllowInvalidHostnames everything works fine, but I do not know how to add it to connection string, so I can use it in mongo shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

> sslVerifyCertificate=false

```
/dbname?replicaSet=XYZ&authSource=admin&ssl=true&sslVerifyCertificate=false
```