# How to connect to Amazon DocumentDB using a connection string?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, aws-documentdb

I am attempting to connect to Amazon DocumentDB cluster via SSH port forwarding as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html).  I can connect using this command ...

```
mongosh --host localhost:27017 --ssl --sslAllowInvalidHostnames --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username REDACTED --password REDACTED
```

... but not this command ...

```
mongosh mongodb://REDACTED:REDACTED@localhost:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

It fails with the error message "unable to get local issuer certificate."  At least one problem is that I have not been able to find any documentation on how to translate the `--sslAllowInvalidHostnames` option into the connection string format.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184828/how-to-use-sslallowinvalidhostnames-in-mongo-connection-string-in-mongo-shell-sc), but adding `&sslVerifyCertificate=false` doesn't change anything so there might be something else I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.tlsAllowInvalidHostnames says it's `tlsAllowInvalidHostnames` now. Out of curiosity why the struggle if you already have it working with command line parameters?

Comment: I need a working connection string to pass into the app I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out (sort of).  I never got the connection string working via mongosh, but when using it to connect in code, which was my ultimate goal, [there are language-specific steps you have to take to install the CA cert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled).  Then you can connect your app with a connection string like this.

```
mongodb://REDACTED:REDACTED@localhost:27017?tls=true&tlsInsecure=true
```

Comment: note `tlsInsecure=true`